# Aligning two strings: Bigramm/Buble

Tags: python, sorting

I am try to write a function that allows me to line up two strings if the characters in both strings match.

for example Input:

output:

```
['H', 'o', 'u', 's', 'e'] ['H', 'o', 's']
```

desired output:

```
['H', 'o', 'u', 's', 'e'] 
['H', 'o', ,'0','s', '0']
```

I was thinking of doing this with something like bubble sort or using bigrams, but I don't have any experience with those.
 Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Comment: `if the characters in both strings match`, could you be more precise? How many of them? And what if the second list is `['H', 's', 'o']`?

Comment: is allowed to sort the lists?

Comment: I meant like if for example if the first two characters of each string are identical.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty approach:

```
l1 = ['H', 'o', 'u', 's', 'e'] 
l2 = ['H', 'o', 's']

l2, l1 = sorted((l1, l2), key=len)
l = len(l1)
j = 0

res = []
for i in range(l):
  try:
    if l1[i]==l2[j]:
      res.append(l1[i])
      j += 1
    else:
      res.append(None)    
  except IndexError:
    res.extend([None] * (l-j))
    break

print(res)  # -> ['H', 'o', None, 's', None]
```

**Note that clarifications are needed! (see @yatu's comment)**

Also note that I changed your `'0'` to `None`. Using `'0'` is a bad idea since, at least in theory, your two initial lists might contain that and you will not be able to differentiate between a match and a non-match.

---

*I am definitely looking forward to a more elegant approach to this interesting problem!*

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a `for` loop and `if else`. You just need to use additional index to keep track over the shorter list

```
list1 = ['H', 'o', 'u', 's', 'e']
list2 = ['H', 'o', 's']
list3 = []

j = 0
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if j < len(list2) and list1[i] == list2[j]:
        list3.append(list1[i])
        j += 1
    else:
        list3.append('0')
    i += 1

print(list3) # ['H', 'o', '0', 's', '0']
```

Or based on `list2`

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if i >= len(list2):
        list2.append('0')
    elif list1[i] != list2[i]:
        list2.insert(i, '0')

print(list2) # ['H', 'o', '0', 's', '0']
```

Answer (score 1):

quick function:

```
def my_func(l1, l2):
    consume_l2 = l2.copy()
    return [l2.pop(l2.index(c)) if c in l2 else '0' for c in l1]

l1 = ['H', 'o', 'u', 's', 'e']
l2 = ['H', 'o', 's']
print(my_func(l1, l2))
```

**output:**

```
['H', 'o', '0', 's', '0']
```

if you do not need the second list you can use :

```
[l2.pop(l2.index(c)) if c in l2 else '0' for c in l1]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already great answers posted here, however, another possibility is to use a class:

```
class Track:
   def __init__(self, v):
      self.v = iter(v)
   def __getitem__(self, val):
      self.v = self.v if (r:=next(self.v, None)) is None or r == val else iter([r, *self.v])
      return '0' if r != val else r

d1, d2 = ['H', 'o', 'u', 's', 'e'], Track(['H', 'o', 's'])
result = [d2[i] for i in d1]
```

Output:

```
['H', 'o', '0', 's', '0']
```